# SQL - Select only latest insertion of each ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL table:

```
autID (auto increment, number) | externalID (NOT unique, string) | title | price | scanDate (datetime)
```

I also have the following query to calculate the average price:

```
SELECT AVG(price) AS avgPrice from rs
```

My goal is to calculate the average price of the latest inserted of each autID only (or based on scanDate). For example:

```
1 | "baba" | 100 | date
2 | "baba | 50| newerDate
3 | "oo | 100| date
```

will return:

```
avgPrice: (50 + 100) / 2 = 75
```

the first `100` is neglected since it's older of the same ID of `baba`

Any idea?

Comment: Break it down in to subqueries. One query to get a list of externalID with most recent date. Then join on that back to the original table and then do an average with group by. Do take into consideration this might not produce expected results if you can have duplicate dates for one externalId value. In that case you need to figure out which price value you want to use (lower or higher).

Comment: Please, [tag your DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use a correlated subquery to get the most recent value and then use average:

```
select avg(rs.price)
from rs
where rs.scandate = (select max(r2.scandate)
                     from rs rs2
                     where rs2.externalid = rs.externalid
                    ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two steps, first find the newest record for each ID, second, do avg()

```
WITH CTE123 AS (
Select ID, Title, MAX(Scandate) as Scandate 
From avgPrice 
GROUP BY ID, Title
)
SELECT avg(rs.price)
FROM avgPrice rs
JOIN CTE123 rp ON rs.id=rp.id and rs.Scandate=rp.Scandate
```

The first step is to find the ID with its newest scandate, and the second step is to join the first CTE and calculate the average for the results. In this way, the calculation is done based on only the newest records.

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.